# Какое максимальное время жизни сессии у express-session?

Tags: node.js, сессия

Все мы знаем что можно ограничить время жизни сессии временем жизни куки как это описано в документации express-session:

```
session.cookie.maxAge
```

На лицо, эффект того что сессия протухла - есть, но если вы посмотрите в `req.sessionStore.sessions` - то увидите что там всё ещё лежат все сессии которые "как-бы" умерли! Собственно вопрос в том, `sessionStore` у `express-session` когда-нибудь очищается? Можно ли свое время очистки ему задать? Пока такой инфы не нашел, вы скажете что конечно можно написать какой-то свой костыль который будет чистить `sessionStore`, но все же может есть и как-то можно настроить встроенный функционал? А если и писать свой костыль, то как понимать что сессия уже отмерла?

В общем интересно узнать по этому поводу кто что скажет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.а. Если используется inMemmory хранилище (а оно используется по умолчанию, если явным видом не указано другого), то сессии не удаляются из памяти, о чем честно написано в логах при запуске приложения. Костыли писать можно, но лучше сразу привыкать использовать отличное от inMemmory хранилище, т.к. упретесь в масштабируемость, а в случае перезапуска - все пользователи будут вас вспоминать нехорошими словами.

1.б. У других хранилищ свой механизм отчистки, за конкретикой лучше лезть в реализацию.

2. Время жизни сессии можно задать через опции, передаваемые при инициализации хранилища.

```js
//это подключение хранилища
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 24*60*60*1000 //вот в этом объекте задается время жизни сессии
  }
}))
```

Все подробности есть в https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookie-options